# Refactoring a test case to stop logging an error

Tags: robotframework

I have a Robot Framework keyword that looks like this:

```
_Open Search Form If Not Open
    ${status}    ${error}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Page Should Contain Element    ${PATIENT SEARCH FORM}
    Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='FAIL'    Click Element    ${PATIENT SEARCH BUTTON}
```

It's intended to only be run if `${PATIENT SEARCH FORM}` isn't open.  However, whenever pybot detects that `Page Should Contain Element` is false, it logs this as an error in the test log.  The test cases that use this keyword pass, and you need to dig into the log to see the failure, but it's still there.  It's not intended to be a failure, though, and I don't want it logged as such.

The real pain is this: I am using Selenium2Library for my tests, and one of its default import options is `run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot`.  I like this functionality, but whenever `Page Should Contain Element` fails and writes a 'FAIL' message to the test log, this functionality fires.  Then the screenshots that are created clutter up my log folder and give a false impression that a test has failed when it hasn't.

What I would like is to either refactor this keyword to not log a failure, or somehow disable Selenium2Library's screenshot functionality for just this keyword.  I used `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` to try to get pybot to ignore the error and not write it to the log, but I must be misinterpreting the meaning of "ignore" here.  A part of the problem is my use of `Page Should Contain Element`.  I'm using a verify keyword, but really, I'm asking "Does the page contain this element?" and not verifying that it does or does not.  I haven't found anything in Selenium2Library that would just return the status of a page element without trying to make an assertion on top of it.  But what I'm essentially trying to do is write a conditional statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then the screenshots that are created clutter up my log folder and give a false impression that a test has failed when it hasn't.

Here is my code to save the screenshots only failed tests

```
*** Settings ***
Library   Selenium2Library   run_on_failure=Nothing
Test Teardown   Test Teardown

*** Test Cases ***
Simple test
    ${status}    ${error}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Page Should Contain Element    ${PATIENT SEARCH FORM}
    Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='FAIL'    Click Element    ${PATIENT SEARCH BUTTON}
    Pass Execution  

*** Keywords ***
Test Teardown
    Run Keyword If Test Failed    Selenium2Library.Capture Page Screenshot
```

Comment: +1 for handling Capture Page Screenshot in Teardown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are expecting will not be possible. The keyword will still be logged and shown as FAIL in your log.html even though your test is passed. To control the screenshot, you can use @Dmitriy Zverev solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
_Open Search Form If Not Open
    ${previous kw}=    Register Keyword To Run On Failure    None
    ${status}    ${error}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Page Should Contain Element ${PATIENT SEARCH FORM}
    Register Keyword To Run On Failure    ${previous kw}
    Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='FAIL'    Click Element    ${PATIENT SEARCH BUTTON}
```

I used `Register Keyword To Run On Failure` to disable screenshot capture temporarily.

Comment: You should probably remember the current setting and then restore it once this code is finished rather than assume it's set to `Capture Page Screenshot`

Comment: You're right. I'll try to find a way to read that and I'll update my answer.